# Obtaining Negative Variance. What is the error?

Tags: statistics, variance

Suppose a dice is thrown $8$ times and success is considered as obtaining either a $5$ or $6$. What is the variance of the number of successes?

**Attempt:** Let the indicator variable $X_i$ be $1$ when either a $5$ or a $6$ turns up on the dice on the $i$th throw and let $X_i$ be $0$ otherwise.

Then: Expected number of successes = $\sum E(X_i)=8 \cdot P(\text{Success}) = 8 \cdot \dfrac{1}{3}$

If $X$ is the total number of success, $E(X^2)= \sum 1^2 \cdot \dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac {8}{3}$

> $Variance = \dfrac{8}{3}- \dfrac{8^2}{3^2} <0$

Where is the error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This $E(X^2)$ should be $E((X_1+...+X_8)^2)$...

Comment: @YuDing Aaah got it. You mean I calculated $\sum E(X^2)$ but what is required is $E~([~\sum X~]~^2)$

Comment: Asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435403/obtaining-negative-variance-what-is-the-error.